# Receive SMS example gives me a garbage values

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, gsm

When I run my [Receive SMS](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesReceiveSMS) example code, By default every time I get the same thing.I am trying to send sms to my sim card present in the Arduino GSM shield. I don't want this message. How to solve this problem ?

[image]

I

Comment: Where is it getting the "trend alert" message from? It's not in the example code.. so is that not the text that it's receiving??

Comment: That is what I am too confused. Every time I run this code, I get this message again and again ...

Comment: This looks like an ad sent to your SIM phone number by your phone operator. Try to use the SIM on a real phone and check if you can get rid of this ad from there.

Comment: @jfpoilpret  No, I am not receiving such sms in my mobile..

Comment: Could you perhaps just copy and paste the text (~200 bytes) instead of pasting an unreadable 100kB image (which also is more effort having to upload it)? And while you are at it, obfuscate the spamvertized domain.

Comment: This is obviously an ad as this links (with complaints about unsolicited SMS ads from this company) shows: http://www.complaintboard.in/complaints-reviews/lenskart-l298415.html

Comment: I have activated DND to my phone, now Its working ...

Comment: Dungeons & Dragons?

Comment: Do not Disturb (DND).

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so that this question is resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Telecom operators agree for sending advertisements and promotions to their customers for certain business and some money. You can stop these promotion for your mobile by making (Do Not Disturb)DND active. In India, just do the following for DND Activation

```
 ( Fully Blocked Category )

 Send SMS at START 0 to 1909 or Call at 1909 


 Partial Blocked Category

Send SMS at START 1 to 1909 to block Banking – Insurance – Financial Products – Credit Cards
Send SMS at START 2 to 1909 to block Real Estate
Send SMS at START 3 to 1909 to block Education
Send SMS at START 4 to 1909 to block Health
Send SMS at START 5 to 1909 to block Consumer Goods & Automobiles
Send SMS at START 6 to 1909 to block Communication – Broadcasting – Entertainment – IT
Send SMS at START 7 to 1909 to block Tourism
```

- See more at: http://www.techsiren.com/how-to-activate-do-not-disturb-india-registration/#sthash.F87Pfj5V.dpuf